# What is $F''(x)$ of function $F(x) = \max\limits_{c\in D}f(x,c)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x,c): \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. What is $F''(x)$ of function $F(x) = \max\limits_{c\in D}f(x,c)$? Is it equal to $\max\limits_{c\in D}f''(x,c)$?
>   Thank you in advace !

Comment: Of course it is not.

Comment: Like, pick $D=[-1,0]$ and $f(x,c)=e^{xc}$. You have that $$\max_{c\in [-1,0]} f(x,c)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if }x\ge0\\ e&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$ is not differentiable and, where it is, the derivative is $0$. However, $\max_{c\in[-1,0]} c^2e^{xc}$ (assuming you mean $f''(x,c)=\partial_x^2f(x,c)$) is positive.

Comment: Your max f(x,c) is not true for $x < 0$. It should be $e^{-x}, x<0$